# Laravel Elixir include Paths for less

Tags: php, less, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'm trying Laravel Elixir and I want to include bootsrap less files with includePaths like in Elixir saass

```
var paths = {
    'bootstrap': './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/'
}

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("style.scss", 'public/assets/css/', {includePaths: [paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/']})
});
```

Is there something similar for less?

Comment: Elixir is a programming language that has nothing to do with this question. Removing the "elixir" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/bower-bootstrap-less-and-elixir:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('application.less', 'public/css', {
        paths: __dirname + '/vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/less'
    });
});
```